# In Perl, mapping between a reference file and a series of files

Tags: perl

I would like to map two data sets in Perl. I have one data set (ref 1) which is unchanging, the other data must be extracted from a series of files (1-20) to match ref1.

```
Ref1
ID1    ID2
1       HZ
1       HX
1       HY
2       C  
2       HZ
2       N

File 1
ID2    ID3
HA      5 
HB      4
HC      7
N       2

File 2
ID2    ID3
C      9
HZ     11
N      0
```

Ideal output:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 
1   HZ   5
1   HX   4 
1   HY   7
2   C    9
2   HZ   11
2   N    0
```

The match occurs between the first letter of ID2 in ref1 with the first letter of ID2 in file1 until matches for all ID1 entries have been made, then file2 is opened and matched against all ID1 numbered 2. The file names have the format number001.txt, number002.txt ect, so ID1 may be retrieved from the file name.

I hope this makes sense. I am a beginner in Perl and this is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ref1 = 'test.txt';
my $input_path = '/path/';

open my $fh, '<' $ref1 or die "Can't read $ref1: $!";
chomp (my @ref1 = <$fh>);

my %hash = @ref1;

my @filehandles;
for ($i=0; $i<20, $i++) {
    local *FILE;
    open(FILE, ">number$i.txt") or die $!;
    push(@filehandles, *FILE);
}
```

Any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think it is:

```
chomp (my @ref1 = <$fh>);
my %hash = @ref1;
```

There's no magic to transpose key/values here - so what you're doing is getting a hash that looks like:

```
      '2       C  ' => '2       HZ',
      'ID1    ID2' => '1       HZ',
      '1       HX' => '1       HY',
      '2       N' => undef
```

Bet that wasn't what you wanted.

I suspect what you may want instead is:

```
    my %ref1;
    while ( <$input> ) {
        chomp;
        my ( $key, $value ) = split;
        push ( @{$ref1{$key}}, $value );
    }
    print Dumper \%ref1;
```

You're also opening your files for writing in your second loop. You probably don't want to do that either.

I'd be going with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $ref1       = 'ref1.txt';
my $input_path = '/path/';

open my $ref1_fh, '<', $ref1 or die "Can't read $ref1: $!";

my %ref1;
while (<$ref1_fh>) {
    chomp;
    next if m/ID/;
    my ( $key, $value ) = split;
    my $zeropadded = sprintf( "%03d", $key );
    my ($firstletter) = ( $value =~ m/^(\w)/ );
    push( @{ $ref1{$zeropadded}{$firstletter} }, $value );

}

print Dumper \%ref1;

print join( "\t", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3" ), "\n";
foreach my $filename ( glob("number*.txt") ) {
    my ($ref_num) = ( $filename =~ m/number(\d+)/ );
    open( my $input, "<", $filename ) or warn $!;
    while (<$input>) {
        chomp;
        my ( $key, $value ) = split;
        my ($firstletter) = ( $key =~ m/^(\w)/ );
        if ( defined $ref1{$ref_num}{$firstletter}
            and @{ $ref1{$ref_num}{$firstletter} } )
        {
            my $refkey = pop( @{ $ref1{$ref_num}{$firstletter} } );

            print join( "\t", int $ref_num, $refkey, $value ), "\n";
        }
    }
    close($input);
}
```

I've converted the 'ref' number to be zero padded, so it matches the filenames directly, as you specify your filename is `number001.txt` matching `1` in `ref1`.

I'm also inserting the contents of `$ref1` into a hash of arrays, keyed on the first letter you're looking for - popping the 'lookup' value until empty.

So we therefore get:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3
1   HY  5
1   HX  4
1   HZ  7
2   C   9
2   HZ  11
2   N   0
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I wasn't sure how to implement the key value pairs but this makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to print all lines of `test.txt` along with the column `ID3` which is defined through a combination of `number*.txt`.

**Edited** (I misundertood the question):

```
##  Save test.txt for later
my $ref = shift;

##  Parse number*.txt
my %id23;
/(\S).* (\S+)/ and
    push @{$id23{$1}}, $2
    while(<>);

##  Combine in print
@ARGV = $ref;
/(.+?) +((.)\S*)/
    and printf "%6s %6s %6s\n", 
        $1, $2, shift @{$id23{$3}}
    while(<>);
```

Run the script with `test.txt` followed by `number*.txt` as arguments.